# phonegap build <platform> - fs.exists error

Tags: cordova

Whenever I attempt to create a PhoneGap 3.0 project in Linux (Lubuntu 13.04, node v0.6.19) I receive the following error:

```
devweinre:test kelvin$ phonegap build android
[phonegap] detecting Android SDK environment...
[phonegap] using the remote environment

/usr/local/lib/node_modules/phonegap/node_modules/phonegap-build/lib/common/config/global.js:45
    fs.exists(filepath, function(exists) {
       ^
TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'exists'
    at Object.load (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/phonegap/node_modules/phonegap-build/lib/common/config/global.js:45:8)
    at PhoneGapBuild.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/phonegap/node_modules/phonegap-build/lib/phonegap-build/login.js:60:19)
    at PhoneGapBuild.login (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/phonegap/node_modules/phonegap-build/lib/phonegap-build/login.js:47:13)
    at PhoneGapBuild.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/phonegap/node_modules/phonegap-build/lib/phonegap-build/build.js:60:10)
    at PhoneGapBuild.build (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/phonegap/node_modules/phonegap-build/lib/phonegap-build/build.js:40:13)
    at RemoteBuildCommand.execute (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/phonegap/lib/phonegap/remote.build.js:74:19)
    at RemoteBuildCommand.run (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/phonegap/lib/phonegap/remote.build.js:54:10)
    at Object.build (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/phonegap/lib/phonegap/util/command.js:28:25)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/phonegap/lib/phonegap/build.js:78:28
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/phonegap/node_modules/cordova/src/platform.js:189:9
```

I have been looking around for an answer and there doesn't appear to be much on the issue. The only really relevant question I could find was [phonegap + Ubuntu 12.04](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18894714/phonegap-ubuntu-12-04). But this did not work for me. This happens for every build (Android/iOS/WP8 etc.). I know iOS will not actually work, but surely it will create a working project - and Android should work - I have all the prerequisites installed.

Can someone help me, as I am not sure how to get this working (I am not an expert with CLI).

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it - my App Name had an apostrophe in it and the command that phonegap was trying to execute could not run because of this.