# cordova phonegap - error installing on Android platform

Tags: android, cordova, ubuntu-12.04

I am new to Cordova and phonegap but have Android working on my ubuntu 12.04.
I followed this [official guide](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.4.0/guide_cli_index.md.html#The%20Command-Line%20Interface) and manage to install cordova.

Despite my machine supports android sdk, when I run this command:

```
cordova platform add android
```

I get the following exception:

```
 *cordova platform add android

 Creating android project...
 /root/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.4.0/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:126
                throw e;
                      ^
Error: An error occurred while listing Android targets
at /root/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.4.0/bin/lib/check_reqs.js:87:29
at _rejected (/root/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.4.0/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:808:24)
at /root/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.4.0/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:834:30
at Promise.when    (/root/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.4.0/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:1079:31)
at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/root/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.4.0/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:752:41)
at /root/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.4.0/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:574:44
at flush (/root/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.4.0/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:108:17)
at process._tickCallback (node.js:415:13)
Error: /root/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.4.0/bin/create: Command failed with exit code 8
at ChildProcess.whenDone (/usr/lib/node_modules/cordova/src/superspawn.js:112:23)
at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
at maybeClose (child_process.js:743:16)
at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:810:5)
root@sergio-Aspire-5755G:/home/sergio/Development/HelloWorld#  cordova platforms ls
Installed platforms: 
Available platforms: android, blackberry10, firefoxos, ubuntu
root@xxx-Aspire-5755G:/home/sergio/Development/HelloWorld# cordova platform add android
Creating android project...
/root/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.4.0/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:126
                throw e;
                      ^
Error: An error occurred while listing Android targets
at /root/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.4.0/bin/lib/check_reqs.js:87:29
at _rejected (/root/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.4.0/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:808:24)
at /root/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.4.0/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:834:30
at Promise.when    (/root/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.4.0/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:1079:31)
at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/root/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.4.0/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:752:41)
at /root/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.4.0/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:574:44
at flush (/root/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.4.0/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:108:17)
at process._tickCallback (node.js:415:13)
Error: /root/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.4.0/bin/create: Command failed with exit  code 8
at ChildProcess.whenDone (/usr/lib/node_modules/cordova/src/superspawn.js:112:23)
at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
at maybeClose (child_process.js:743:16)
at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:810:5)*
```

I tried and see other post like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18894714/phonegap-ubuntu-12-04) but noone helped me.

Android sdk version 19 is installed

Comment: You're folling doc for phonegap 2.9 and using cordova 3.4... things have changed a lot between 2.9 and 3.X

Comment: Try to run `$home/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.4.0/bin/check_reqs` to see if it displays a clearer message about the error.

Comment: this is what I get:~/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.4.0/bin# ./check_reqs
[Error: An error occurred while listing Android targets]

Comment: if you run the `android` command does it start the sdk manager? If yes ensure you installed the sdk 19.

Comment: yes it starts the sdkmanager and the v 19 is installed, I ll update my question

Comment: I haven't cordova 3.4 so I'll not be able to help you more. What you can do is open check_reqs.js at line 87 and see what command it's trying to launch. I can't find it but I remember I helped someone with a similar issue and the cause had something to do with the path of the project or the project name.

Comment: I solved adding it to my .bashrc: export PATH=$PATH:/opt/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20131030/sdk/platform-tools:/opt/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20131030/sdk/tools. This post can be closed

Comment: possible duplicate of [An error occurred while listing Android targets](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23466479/an-error-occurred-while-listing-android-targets)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this way:

adding the below line to my .bashrc:

**export PATH=$PATH:/opt/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20131030/sdk/platform-tools:/opt/adt-bun‌​dle-linux-x86_64-20131030/sdk/tools**

Answer (score 1):

1) run "android avd" command and create at least one virtual device based on a version of a previously downloaded SDK.

2) sudo apt-get install ant1.8

```
worked for me.
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to check if path to Android SDK is correct or not.
 Check your Environment Variables PATH, ANDROID_PLATFORM_TOOLS, ANDROID_HOME, ANT_HOME  you can check if they are configured correctly by `echo %ANDROID_HOME%` check for all Paths you will know which path is not configured properly.