# An error occurred while listing Android targets

Tags: android, ios, cordova, ant

I am getting this same error while trying to `add platform Android` to simple HelloWorld application created using `CLI Cordova` on Windows 8.

Path vaiables has been set for
**%ANT%,%ANT_HOME%,%ANDROID_HOME%**
PATH Also contains 
**%ANDROID_HOME%\platform-tools**  and **%ANDROID_HOME%\tools** in the listings.

```
PS E:\Android Projects\HelloWorld> cordova platforms add android
Creating android project...

C:\Users\MIGHTY\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.4.0\bin\node_modules\q\q.js:126
                throw e;
                      ^
Error: An error occurred while listing Android targets
    at C:\Users\MIGHTY\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.4.0\bin\lib\check_reqs.js:87:29
    at _rejected       (C:\Users\MIGHTY\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.4.0\bin\node_modules\q\q.js:808:24)
at C:\Users\MIGHTY\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.4.0\bin\node_modules\q\q.js:834:30
at Promise.when (C:\Users\MIGHTY\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.4.0\bin\node_modules\q\q.js:1079:31)
at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (C:\Users\MIGHTY\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.4.0\bin\node_modules\q\q.js:752:41)
at C:\Users\MIGHTY\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.4.0\bin\node_modules\q\q.js:574:44
at flush (C:\Users\MIGHTY\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.4.0\bin\node_modules\q\q.js:108:17)
at process._tickCallback (node.js:415:13)
Error: C:\Users\MIGHTY\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.4.0\bin\create.bat: Command failed with exit code 8
at ChildProcess.whenDone (C:\Users\MIGHTY\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\src\superspawn.js:126:23)
at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
at maybeClose (child_process.js:743:16)
at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:810:5)
```

Simillar error is being raised while trying to create the same on iOS also.

```
PS E:\Android Projects\HelloWorld> cordova platforms add ios
Creating ios project...
Error: C:\Users\MIGHTY\.cordova\lib\ios\cordova\3.4.1\bin\create: Command failed with       exit code ENOENT
at ChildProcess.whenDone (C:\Users\MIGHTY\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\src\superspawn.js:126:23)
at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:795:12)
```

---

**Solved:**

Thank you, [the issue with Android has been resolved](http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/managing-avds-cmdline.html).

The path variable pointing to this android was wrong. I had used **%ANDROID_HOME%** as variable and scaled the same to path variables **%ANDROID_HOME%\SDK\TOOLS**. This method doesn't work. Experimentally resolved by directly pointing to the Tools and Platform Tools.

Comment: Followed your solution of pointing directly to tools and platform-tools in Path and it worked for me, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can't add the iOs platform on Windows 8 (Check the available commands on the link):

> "Your ability to run these commands depends on whether your machine supports each SDK, and whether you have already installed each SDK."
>   *source: http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.4.0//guide_cli_index.md.html#The%20Command-Line%20Interface*

Android is strange though.. Can you provide any more details? (are all the environment variables set correctly? did you add JAVA_HOME?..)

Hopefully I'll be more of a help with some more info :)

Comment: Thank You, The issue with the ANDROID has been resolved. http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/managing-avds-cmdline.html. The path variable pointing to this android was wrong. I had used %ANDROID_HOME% as variable and scaled the same to path variables %ANDROID_HOME%\SDK\TOOLS. This method doesn't work. Experimentally resolved by directly pointing to the Tools and Platform Tools.

Comment: Cool, didn't know that as well.. glad you worked it out!

Comment: If you have a partial answer and need clarification from the OP, please consider leaving your feedback as a comment instead of posting an answer. As it stands, the accepted answer to this question does not provide a full solution.